# Warning: Missing argument 3 for DB::update(), called in

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I'm getting the following error message:

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for DB::update(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\my.sleeptrak.com\users\step-1-edit.php on line 51 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\my.sleeptrak.com\users\classes\DB.php on line 261

Here is my db.php:

```php
    public function update($table, $id, $fields){
        $sql   = "UPDATE {$table} SET " . (empty($fields) ? "" : "`") . implode("` = ? , `", array_keys($fields)) . (empty($fields) ? "" : "` = ? ");
        $is_ok = true;

        if (!is_array($id)) {
            $sql     .= "WHERE id = ?";
            $fields[] = $id;
        } else {
            if (empty($id))
                return false;

            if ($where_text = $this->_calcWhere($id, $fields, "and", $is_ok))
                $sql .= "WHERE $where_text";
        }

        if ($is_ok)
            if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error())
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

And here is my edit.php

```php
<form class="needs-validation" method="post">
                <div class="offset-2 col-md-8 order-md-1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <?php
                            if(isset($_POST['save'])) {

                                $fields = array(
                                    "PatientFirstName"  =>  $_POST['PatientFirstName'],
                                    "PatientLastName"       =>  $_POST['PatientLastName'],
                                    "PatientStreet"         =>  $_POST['PatientStreet'],
                                    "PatientCity"               =>  $_POST['PatientCity'],
                                    "PatientProvince"       =>  $_POST['PatientProvince'],
                                    "PatientPostalCode" =>  $_POST['PatientPostalCode'],
                                    "PatientCountry"        =>  $_POST['PatientCountry'],
                                    "PatientEmail"          =>  $_POST['PatientEmail'],
                                    "PatientPhone"          =>  $_POST['PatientPhone'],
                                    "PatientDOB"                =>  $_POST['PatientDOB'],
                                    "PatientBMI"                =>  $_POST['PatientBMI'],
                                    "PhysicianName"         =>  $_POST['PhysicianName'],
                                    "PhysicianEmail"        =>  $_POST['PhysicianEmail']
                                );

                                $db->update("patients", $fields);
                                //print_r($db->errorInfo());

                                echo '<div class="alert alert-success mb-4" role="alert">The patient has been successfully updated!</div>';

                            } else {
                            ?>
                          <h4 class="mb-3">Edit Patient <?php echo $PatientFirstName . ' ' . $PatientLastName; ?></h4>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <label for="PatientFirstName">Patient first name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientFirstName" value="<?php echo $PatientFirstName; ?>">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Valid first name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <label for="PatientLastName">Patient last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientLastName" value="<?php echo $PatientLastName; ?>">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Valid last name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label for="PatientDOB">Patient DOB</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="PatientDOB" value="<?php echo $PatientDOB; ?>">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientEmail" value="<?php echo $PatientFirstName; ?>">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label for="PatientPhone">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientPhone" value="<?php echo $PatientPhone; ?>">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Valid last name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div><!--card-body-->
                    </div><!--card-->


                    <div class="card mt-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>Patient Address</h4>
                                <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                            <label for="PatientStreet">Street</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientStreet" value="<?php echo $PatientStreet; ?>">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Valid address is required.</div>
                          </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label for="PatientCity">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientCity" value="<?php echo $PatientCity; ?>">
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            City is required.
                                        </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                        <label for="state">Province / State</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientProvince" value="<?php echo $PatientProvince; ?>">
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Please provide a valid province/state.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                        <label for="PatientPostalCode">Postal Code / Zip</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientPostalCode" value="<?php echo $PatientPostalCode; ?>">
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Postal Code / Zip Code is required.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                                        <label for="PatientCountry">Country</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientCountry" value="<?php echo $PatientCountry; ?>">
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Please select a valid country.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div><!--card-body-->
                    </div><!--card-->


                    <div class="card mt-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>Body Mass Index</h4>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label for="PatientBMI">Patient BMI</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PatientBMI" value="<?php echo $PatientBMI; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div><!--card-body-->
                    </div><!--card-->

                    <div class="card mt-3">
                        <div class="card-body">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label for="PhysicianName">Physician Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PhysicianName" value="<?php echo $PhysicianName; ?>">
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Valid last name is required.</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label for="PhysicianEmail">Physician Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PhysicianEmail" value="<?php echo $PhysicianEmail; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div><!--card-body-->
                    </div><!--card-->


                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mt-4" name="save" type="submit">Update</button>
                </div>


                      </form>
```

I research all same errors on this form but i can't fix it. I tried to replace this: `php public function update($table, $id, $field)` with this `public function update($table, $id, $fields=null)` but is not working for me. How ever, the error is gone when i put null in function but still don't save in db my changes.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write all arguments for update method

`$db->update("patients", $id, $fields);`

you missed $id.

Comment: is not working, i tried that and i get this notice: ```Notice: Undefined index: id in```

Comment: because you have not $id variable.

Comment: `1. create on your form <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $PatientId ?>">`

`2. then get it on php side $id = $_POST['id']`

`3. then use here $db->update("patients", $id, $fields);`

Comment: OK, maybe i'm tired because it's late in my country but i can't fix it. I create the input here: ```<div class="card"><div class="card-body"> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />``` becouse i don't have "$patiendId", after that ```$id = $_POST['id'];```and the final i put this ```$db->update("patients", $id, $fields);``` . i have same error with my $id variable...

Comment: I wrote patiendId as an example. could you show how did you do that?

Comment: yes. fist i create in my form that input:                                                                   
   ```<form class="needs-validation" method="post">
    <div class="offset-2 col-md-8 order-md-1">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
       "some code:
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success mb-4" role="alert">The patient has been successfully updated!</div>';

       }```

Comment: That $id i think is incorect. becouse the that variable need to get from mysql to know where updated

Comment: firstly you need to get data from the table. I do not see that. That is why I wrote to you only last step.

Comment: done. thanks. i didn't call correctly the $id variable from my db. now its working.